# javascript get return function when using call

Tags: javascript, validation

i call function javascript using call() but call() not return

```
config.validar = function(){
    cases.validarNuevoPaso(form);   
}

var resp = config.validar.call(undefined, form);

validarNuevoPaso : function(form){
    return 'algun valor';
}
```

and resp is undefined,

thanks for help.

Comment: Try to elaborate a bit more. I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what form validation library you're using.

Comment: @Joost I think you mean *Try to elaborate more*. *Being* elaborate is different.

Comment: You're right. I had my Thesaurus upside down ;) Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the string from `validarNuevoPaso` to `validar` but not returning anything from `validar` - insert a return statement to get it all the way out

```
config.validar = function(){
    return cases.validarNuevoPaso(form);   
}
```